# Flex not wrapping for mobile responsiveness

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to find what I am doing wrong, as it appears that this does not want to work.  All I'm trying to do is get the footer boxes, to be in a row (when on desktop), and then mobile, have these stacked with the display flex css tags but I've tried everything and does not seem to want to work. If I put column then it does on both.

Website is displayable at `shop.bridgetsarah.co.uk`.

```
    <div class="footer">
    <div class="widget1">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'ft1' ); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="widget2">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'ft2' ); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="widget3">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'ft3' ); ?>
    </div>
    
    </div>

    footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap; 
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 75%;
    background-color: yellow;
  
   
    }


    .widget1{
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    }
   .widget2{
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    }
   .widget3{
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    }
```

Comment: Add point before the `footer {` to be `.footer {`

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

1. You should give flex properties to the wrapper (footer), not the items itself
2. In HTML you have used `<div class="footer">` but in CSS you directly tried to style the `footer` tag. Change it to `.footer` or use `<footer>` tag instead of `<div>`

I have updated your code below and hope it helps you :)

```css
.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  text-align: center;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .footer {
    flex-direction: column
  }
}

.widget1 {
  width: 30%;
}

.widget2 {
  width: 30%;
}

.widget3 {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="widget1">
    FT1
  </div>
  <div class="widget2">
    FT2
  </div>
  <div class="widget3">
    FT3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Add @media Queries

```css
 .footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap; 
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 75%;
    background-color: yellow;
    }
    .widget1{
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    }
   .widget2{
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    }
   .widget3{
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    }

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .footer {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="footer">
    <div class="widget1">
            111111111111
    </div>
    <div class="widget2">
            222222222222
    </div>
    <div class="widget3">
            33333333333
    </div>

    </div>
```